# A script that notifies you about posts related to you?

Tags: support, app-request

I'm looking for a script that can notify a user about posts (by others) that include a link to their profile or any of their posts. Does one exist?

Comment: Not possible wit the API due to quota limitations.  Use the [data.se].

Comment: You could probably do this with a combination of [search](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) for profile links and [/questions/{ids}/linked](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/linked-questions).

Comment: @BrockAdams is this still not possible?

Comment: @Tim, Something that's "close enough" might be doable on lower traffic sites.  Pretty sure it will still bust quota on sites like [so] for at least some users -- especially when polling is factored in.